# Uniqueness of solutions to linear recurrence relations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I understand that if I have a linear homogeneous recurrence relation of the form $q_n = c_1 q_{n-1} + c_2 q_{n-2} + \cdots + c_d q_{n-d}$, I can construct the characteristic polynomial $p(t) = t^d - c_1 t^{d-1} - \cdots - c_{d-1} t - c_d$, and if the roots are $r_1, \ldots, r_d$ (say distinct, for simplicity)
I can be assured that $q_n = k_1 r_1^n + \cdots k_d r_d^n$ is a solution for any choice of coefficients $k_i$.  But are these the *only* solutions?  Is there a clean way to show this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can see it by observing that the set of all solutions is a vector space of dimension $d$; this holds because if you choose $q_1,\ldots q_d$, the rest is clearly determined. The solutions $\{r_i^n\}$ are linearly independent (which can be shown by Vandermond determinant, for example), so they generate the whole space.

Comment: This is a nice reason, thanks!  I'll go through it carefully in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is proven in these 3 textbooks. 1. Saber Elaydi, *An Introduction to Difference Equations* (2005 3 ed). Pages 66, 126.

> [image]

> [image]

2. Walter G. Kelley, *Difference equations an introduction with applications* by (2001 2 ed), p 50.

[image]

3. Mickens, Ronald E, *Difference Equations Theory, Applications and Advanced Topics* (2015 3 ed), pp 84-85.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).